# Bounded run Binary Smirnov words counting (Numberphile video)

Tags: combinatorics, popular-math

The [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP-Ipsat90c). What Simon is counting are Smirnov words with bounded runs. [This blog](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/the-generating-function-for-smirnov-words-or-time-until-k-consecutive-results-are-the-same/) gives the generating function to get these numbers, but in the part of direct counting it does not provide a way. This is what I am looking for.

Fortunately, this same blog suggests a way to get these words: we start with the Smirnov words (which in the binary case are very simple) with size $\le n$ and repeat some characters until we get a word of size $n$, taken care of not getting runs of 1 or 0 longer than $k$. In this way, we can relate the number of binary words without runs of more than $k$ with integer solutions of equations like
$$ x_1+\ldots+x_j = m $$ with $0\le x_i< k-1$. The number of these can be obtained with the inclusion exclusion formula. Finally, with a bit of rearranging we arrive to the following formula
$$ 2\sum_{a=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor} (-1)^a \sum_{l=1}^{n-ak} \binom{l}{a}\binom{n-1-ak}{l-1}~~.\tag{1}$$ Note that the first term is $2^n$. I wonder if $(1)$ can be simplified further. With $n=20$ and $k=3$, expression $(1)$ predicts 242830, consistent with the video ([at 6:19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP-Ipsat90c&t=6m19s)). There is also an additional calculation done in the video, counting the words with a single run of $4$ ones or zeroes. What is a formula for that calculation?

Comment: I think where you wrote $m$ in the first displayed equation, you meant $n$? In the blog, $m$ is the size of the alphabet, and you seem to have fixed that at $m=2$; and you're consistently using $n$ for the length of the words everywhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt this can be simplified. Similar sums arise in the problem of [balls in bins with limited capacity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm), and I've never seen them simplified.

Comment: As regards the additional calculation, a) I think it would be better to ask that in a separate question, and b) I didn't immediately see that at the point in the video where your link starts; you should provide a link specific to that calculation so people don't have to watch large parts of the video to answer the question.